# selecting certain column after a join operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql:

```
  SELECT a.member_id, b.date, b.type, d.K_id, d.title, a.login
    FROM members as a
    JOIN permissions as b ON b.member_id = a.member_id
    JOIN titles as d ON d.k_id = b.k_id
   WHERE a.member_id = '$member'
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

I want to select the login where type equals '3'.  Can this be done without another select query?

I should rephrase based on the answers below .....I meant I wanted to select where type = 3 FROM the results of this query.

Comment: With the queries in the answers you will be selecting the records where type = 3 from the results of the query. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.member_id, b.date, b.type, d.K_id, d.title, a.login
FROM members as a
JOIN permissions as b
ON b.member_id = a.member_id
JOIN titles as d
ON d.k_id = b.k_id
WHERE a.member_id = '$member' and b.type = '3'
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

or

```
WHERE a.member_id = '$member' and b.type = 3
```

depending on the type of type.

Comment: That will select the elements from the results where type = 3

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT a.member_id, b.date, b.type, d.K_id, d.title, a.login
FROM members as a
JOIN permissions as b
ON b.member_id = a.member_id
JOIN titles as d
ON d.k_id = b.k_id
WHERE a.member_id = '$member' AND b.type = '3'
ORDER BY b.date DESC
```